# AngularJS + HTTPS

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https

I have an Angular application running on a Live server with an SSL certificate.

The application uses MVC5 + Web API with Individual User Authentication on the server.

Using Chrome's Developer Tools, I am tracking the Network traffic to view data send to over HTTPS.

When I log into the app, it shows me the FORM DATA containing my login creditials?

Also tested on IE and it displays my login credentials in the REQUEST BODY?

Does this mean that the request to the server are not using HTTPS?

I have also, tried to use Fiddler with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

data visible under **Form Data** is fine. Chrome developer tools will show you all the parameters passed to the server irrespective of protocol. Check for the values in **Request URL** and **Request Method** under **General** section. They are important. For security purpose they should have **https** (along with your domain) and **POST** for login service.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser see https data unencrypted. Otherwise, it couldn't display the webpage.